# If a recursive sequence converges, must its inverse be divergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, divergent-series, recursion

Suppose I have a recursive sequence $\displaystyle a_{n+1} = \frac{a_{n}}{2}$. Clearly, the sequence converges towards zero. Now, suppose I define an "inverse" sequence $\displaystyle b_{n+1} = 2b_{n}$. While the sequence clearly diverges, could I know that based on the knowledge that $a_{n+1}$ converges? Is there any sequence that converges, whose "inverse" also converges?

.. and could this "inverse" sequence be defined in a more intuitive way?

Comment: Suppose we have $a_n=a_{n+1}$ with $a_0=1$, then the sequence converges as well its reciprocal. So in general the answer will be no.

Comment: The sequence $a_{n+1}=a_{n}$ would also have it's "inverse" converge.

Comment: Is it still no if we assume that $a_n \neq a_{n+1}$?

Comment: Yes, it is no. Use $1+\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: I'd call it "reverse".

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Reverse does also make sense, but my interpretation of his notion is that if a sequence is defined by $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ for bijective $f$, the inverse sequence is $b_{n+1} = f^{-1}(b_n)$

Comment: Yes, I'm after what G. H. Faust wrote. So it seems there is no simple constraint that would make this property hold for a "large" set of functions? Thank you Andre for $1 + \frac{1}{n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say the sequence $(a_n)$ defined by $a_{n+1} = f(a_n)$ for bijective $f$ converges to $a$.

If $f$ is continuous at $a$, then
$$0 = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_
{n+1}-a_n = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(a_n)-a_n = f(a)-a$$

So $f(a)=a$. But then it also follows that $f^{-1}(a)=a$.
So if the inverse sequence is started with seed value $b_0 = a$, the inverse sequence will converge also.

I'm not $100$% sure what can be said for such convergent recurrences where $f$ is not continuous at the limit.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence $a_{k+1} = \sinh(a_k)$. If started at $a_0=\exp(i \pi/4)$ then this converges to $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n=0$.
Now look at the inverse $ a_{k-1} = \operatorname{asinh}(a_k)$. you can step backwards to arrive at $a_0$ again and go to $\lim_{n \to -\infty} a_n=0$ 
When I came across it this surprised me much. See a picture here: [image: Bild]